# iOS Obj C Typhoon Auto Inject in a View

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have an iOS App with DI (Typhoon).
In the Assembly I wrote this:

```
- (AvPlayerManager *)playerManager {
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AvPlayerManager class]
                      configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition)
        {
            definition.scope = TyphoonScopeSingleton;
        }]; }
```

I can use this AvPlayerManager class in a ViewControllerA.h with auto injection:`@property (nonatomic, weak) InjectedClass(AvPlayerManager) playerManager;` 
I have a collectionView and I want to use the playerManager in the cells.
But If I try with the injectedClass macro the property will be nil.

My UI:

viewControllerA -> collectionView -> collectionViewCell

How can I use this singleton instance in the collectionViewCell.m?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to declare you injected dependencies privately in the implementation (.m) rather than in the header?

The way to do this is to use a class extension inside the implementation file, for example:

*MyFile.m*

```
@interface AudioManager() // or whatever your class is called in .h

@property (nonatomic, weak) InjectedClass(AvPlayerManager) playerManager; 

@end

//rest of .m implementation follows.
```

By the way, if you're using Swift in the future you might like to check out Typhoon's Swift successor, which is called [pilgrim.ph](https://pilgrim.ph).

If I understood your question correctly great, otherwise could you please clarify.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Sorry if my question was not enough clear. So I edited my question.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to be doing that. Instead you have an AudioManager class that knows how to play a source. When the cell is tapped it notifies the audio manager (via a view controller for example) that the audio should play now. . . if you are sure you wanted to, since you make the cell via a VC or view, you can just pass it in as an initializer arg. . Did you see the Typhoon example app?